# Refresh Div on Fancybox Close

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fancybox

How do I refresh a div on a parent page with I close Fancybox.  I know I can put onClosed: function(), but I don't have a clue what function to put in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would call whatever function you call to load the content of the div in the first place.

Comment: I'm just running a PHP query to the database

Comment: Then you would either have to refresh the whole page or write some JS that makes an Ajax call back to your PHP that returned JUST the data for that div, then load it dynamically. You cannot update *just* a DIV with content supplied from the server without an Ajax request back to that server.

Comment: yeah, I wanted to do some sort of ajax

Comment: so I would need to do the .load(phpfile.php) for this?

Comment: Does the PHP file contain *only* what belongs in the DIV? If it doesn't then you might want to try .load('phpfile.php #idOfDIVThatContainsData')

Comment: well when I make the PHP file i will just have a loop of what belongs in that div.  What does the added #ID do to the load function?

Comment: The added #ID will only load the content of an element with that ID from the called page. If the called page *only* has what you need, then you on't need that. If it has other stuff and you only want the contents of a specific div, then you would need it

Comment: Yeah, that's what I said first, that reloads the whole page (which isn't Ajax).

Comment: So, if my main page is called index.php, and my div is called "main", then I would say .load('phpfile.php #main').  The PHP file would contain the PHP loop for what goes in main?  Could I add parameters for phpfile.php though, for ex. phpfile.php?id=1&div=main????

Comment: I guess I just don't know what to put in the external php file cause everytime I try the .load it never works

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you have to pass the context (in this case, window.opener) to jquery:

```
onClose: function(){
    $("#myId", window.opener).doStuff();
}
```

Comment: 'onClosed': function(){window.location.reload();}

Comment: window.opener would relate to a popup window not a lightbox